# Get Timezone date and time using PHP

Tags: php, date, time, timezone

Is there a way to get specific timezone without changing the default timezone?
I tried to use this code to get the timezone but when I revert back its not different output.

```
echo '<br />'.date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '<br />';
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Melbourne'); 
echo '<br />' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago'); 
echo '<br />' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Output:
2013-08-15 03:24:48
2013-08-15 13:24:48
2013-08-14 22:24:48

as the output the last row added a time.

Comment: Have you tried `date_default_timezone_get()` to determine the current timezone?

Comment: The last stated default timezone that is echo'ed in your code will be used as the default timezone. You can't mix them.

Answer (score 2):

According to [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [datetime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.time.php) formats, you can do something like:

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime(date("H:i:s")." America/Chicago"));
```

Or even better:

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("now America/Chicago"));
```

Answer (score 0):

> ## ✓ The following code will output:

---

#### Australia/Melbourne time - 2013-08-15 13:48:57

#### America/New_York - 2013-08-14 23:48:57

```
<?php

echo "Australia/Melbourne time - ";
$now = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('Australia/Melbourne'));
echo $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

echo "<br>";

echo "America/New_York - ";

$now = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
echo $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

?>
```